# Microsoft Access after splitting no longer able to input values?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form that auto populates with values from a table. The code below worked great before I split the access file. But it no longer fills in the empty text boxes. Thanks for any help!

```
    'Finds the new tag number
    'Define components
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    'SQL statement broken up in parts
    strSQL = "SELECT Top 1 IncomingCoilTable.[Tag #] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM IncomingCoilTable "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY IncomingCoilTable.[Tag #] DESC "
    
    'Setting the statement to variable
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    myValue = rs.Fields(0)
    NewCoilNumber.Value = myValue + 1
```

Comment: Have you step debugged? Could use DMax() domain aggregate function instead of opening a recordset object. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Debugger didnt come up with anything, but to give context this happens on form loading. Im not attached to the naming convention so that can change

Comment: So code does execute? But variables are not getting values?

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) @jeremykleiber

Comment: This code doesn't match your problem description. Where are you loading text boxes? Have you tried dumping the SQL and testing it from inside a query? Are you getting any records back from your recordset?

Answer (score 0):

Put in top of your module:

```
Option Explicit
```

Specify your variable:

```vb
 'Define components
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strSQL  As String
    Dim myValue As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'SQL statement broken up in parts
    strSQL = "SELECT Top 1 IncomingCoilTable.[Tag #] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM IncomingCoilTable "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY IncomingCoilTable.[Tag #] DESC "
    
    'Setting the statement to variable
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    myValue = rs.Fields(0).Value
    NewCoilNumber.Value = myValue + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the help, I managed to roll back a version and I split it and it worked great. Not sure why it didn't work before nor do I understand why the debugger wasn't working. Just happy it works now!